# Handson Tableを使ったスプレッドシートの開発

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

HandsonTableを使ってスプレッドシートの開発を行っております。
ソースは下記alertの部分はチェック用で実際にはajaxでサーバに送信しようとしています。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/handsontable.full.css">
  <scriptsrc="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/handsontable.full.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    var logs = $('#logs'),
    gridContainer = document.getElementById('grid'),
    selectedRow = 0,
    selectedCol = 0,
    gridTable = new Handsontable(gridContainer, {
        data: getData(),
        minSpareRows: 1,
        rowHeaders: true,
        contextMenu: true,
        afterChange: function(changes, source) {
            if (source == 'edit') {
                for (var i = 0; i < changes.length; i++) {
                    var rowChange = changes[i];
                }
            }
        },
    });
    $(document).on('click', '#btn-consoledata', function (e) {
        var statdata =  gridTable.getData();
        alert(statdata);
    });
  });
  var getData = function () {
    return [
        ['A','B','C'],
        ["1","2","3"],
        ["4","5","6"],
        ["7","8","9"],
    ];
  };
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <div><button id="btn-consoledata">OK</button></div>
    <div id="grid"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

このソースを下記の手順で実行
①画面を表示
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
②データを修正
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
③OKを押しアラートが表示
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上記のように変更データは取得できているのですが、
データ形式がcsvとなっていて列数がわかりません。
列数を取得する方法、もしくは配列のままデータを取得する方法など、ご教授願えれば幸いです。
何卒よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`getData()`は二次元配列を返していませんか。`alert(statdata[0]);`とすれば一行目だけ表示されると思います。
`alert`が二次元配列をCSVのように表示しているだけのような気がします。

- 行数と列数の取得には`countRows()`と`countCols()`というメソッドがありますので、こちらを使うと便利です。
- シンプルにデータを取得するなら、上記関数と`getDataAtCell(row, col)`を使用すれば、任意の場所を取得することができます。
- もしくは`getDataAtCol(col)`と`getDataAtRow(row)`を使用して一列(一行)をまとめて取得することもできます。